# Formatting DataGrid Column based on user column selection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, wpfdatagrid, mvvm-light

I have a ComboBox( collection of available columns ) in the headertemplate of the gridview.

Initially the grid is binded to a datatable which has column names starting from A,B..Z and 50 rows. ( initial setup ).

When a user selects a column from combobox , I need to reformat the complete column based on the column name selected in the header of the GridView.

Ex:-
If user chooses currency as the column , all existing values in that `GridViewColumn` should be modified in currency format. or any other formats `"{0:d}"`

How can I approach to solve this ? I'm using MVVM , WPF DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54645/WPF-ListView-which-can-do-Sorting-Filtering-Totals

Helped me to accomplish the task , i have to rewrite few code parts and it works great !!!